# How to increase and decrease a date in weekly format in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Weekly increment and decrement counter on tap of buttons. How to achieve this in flutter.

```
class DateCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  const DateCounter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DateCounter> createState() => _DateCounterState();
}

class _DateCounterState extends State<DateCounter> {
  final _inputStartFormat = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
  var weekFirstDay;
  var weekLastDay;
  late DateTime startDateTime;
  late DateTime endDateTime;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    startDateTime = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day);
    weekFirstDay = _inputStartFormat.format(startDateTime);
    debugPrint("start new $startDateTime");
    endDateTime = endDateWeekly(startDateTime);
    debugPrint("start end $endDateTime");
    weekLastDay = _inputStartFormat.format(endDateTime);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                weeklySubtractFunc();
              }, child: Container(
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: const Center(child: Text("-")))),
            Text("$weekFirstDay To $weekLastDay"),
            InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                weeklyAddFunc();
              },
                child: Container(
                  width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: const Center(child: Text("+"))))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  DateTime endDateWeekly(DateTime startDate) {
    return DateTime(startDate.year, startDate.month, startDate.day)
        .add(const Duration(days: 7 - 1));
  }

  DateTime addWeekly(DateTime date, int days, bool isForward) {
    return
      DateTime(date.year, date.month, isForward ? date.day + 7 : date.day - 7);
  }

  void weeklyAddFunc() {
    startDateTime = addWeekly(startDateTime, 7, true);
    weekFirstDay = _inputStartFormat.format(startDateTime);
    endDateTime = endDateWeekly(startDateTime);
    weekLastDay = _inputStartFormat.format(endDateTime);
    debugPrint("add Func $startDateTime");
    debugPrint("add Func 2 $endDateTime");
    setState(() {});
  }

  void weeklySubtractFunc() {
    startDateTime = addWeekly(startDateTime, -7, false);
    weekFirstDay = _inputStartFormat.format(startDateTime);
    endDateTime = endDateWeekly(startDateTime);
    weekLastDay = _inputStartFormat.format(endDateTime);
    debugPrint("sub Func $startDateTime");
    debugPrint("sub Func 2 $endDateTime");
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Initially it need to show current week start and end date as 19-02-2023 to 25-02-2023
decrement button it need to show previous week as 12-02-2023 to 18-02-2023
increase button need to upcoming week 26-02-2023 to 04-03-2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are better ways to do this with date functions, but this is what I came up with.

Add a function to determine the start of a week, by backtracing until correct weekday (You want it to start with Sunday, that is weekday = 7):

```
  DateTime getStartOfWeek(DateTime date) {
    var newDate = DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day);
    while (newDate.weekday != 7) {
      newDate = newDate.add(const Duration(days: -1));
    }
    return newDate;
  }
```

Then it's just a matter of adding 6 days to get the end of the week or 7 days to get next/previous week:

```
  DateTime getEndOfWeek(DateTime startOfWeek) {
    return startOfWeek.add(const Duration(days: 6));
  }

  DateTime getNextWeek(DateTime startOfWeek) {
    return startOfWeek.add(const Duration(days: 7));
  }

  DateTime getPreviousWeek(DateTime startOfWeek) {
    return startOfWeek.add(const Duration(days: -7));
  }
```

So start by getting the start of the current week and the end of the same week:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startDate = getStartOfWeek(DateTime.now());
    endDate = getEndOfWeek(startDate);
  }
```

And then use the functions above in your onTap events to set the new state:

```
  void increaseWeek() {
    setState((){
      startDate = getNextWeek(startDate);
      endDate = getEndOfWeek(startDate);
    });
  }

  void decreaseWeek() {
    setState((){
      startDate = getPreviousWeek(startDate);
      endDate = getEndOfWeek(startDate);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi cmbellman exactly ur solution got worked thanks again.....!!!

Answer (score 2):

```dart
DateTime getNewDateTime(DateTime date, int days, bool isForward) {
  return isForward
      ? date.add(Duration(days: days))
      : date.subtract(Duration(days: days));
}
```